# java socket.read to b[] ignore region mapped from JNI

Tags: java, c++, sockets, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I mapped byte array region from native.

```
jbyteArray ar = env->NewByteArray(len);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(ar, 0, len, (jbyte*) buf);
...
```

then call java socket receive

```
public int socketReceive (Socket sock, byte[] ar)
{
    int nrecv = 0;
    try
    {
        nrecv = sock.getInputStream().read(ar);

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }

    return nrecv;
}
```

result is nothing wrote to

```
(jbyte*) buf
```

and

```
byte[] ar
```

actually contain received data, but in new byte region

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you should expect. SetByteArrayRegion() *copies* the data from 'buf' to 'ar[]'. It doesn't adjust 'ar[]' to point to 'buf'. See the JNI Specification.